# Restrict Python API access to single Arduino entity

Tags: python, api, flask, arduino

I am basically writing an API in Python, using Flask, and I would like to restrict access to its endpoints so that only an entity, namely an Arduino, can have GET and POST access. How should I make this possible and what should I be looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a secret key (i.e. a password) to each client of this API, and then require that this key is provided by the client with all requests sent to the server.

So you start by assigning a key to your Arduino client, but you can also give a different key to your own testing client, and any other development clients you may need.

The secret key can be passed as [HTTP Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) with every request.

Comment: This is what I was thinking about also. I thought there would be a more robust solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Configure your WSGI container or its associated web server to only allow access to the Flask application from the IP address assigned to the Arduino's network interface.

Comment: Since I am writing only the API, I don't have much experience with Arduino. Is the IP address assigned to the Arduino a static one, so that I can hardcode it in my Flask API?

Comment: That completely depends on how it's been configured.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to figure it out. Will come back later if I don't manage. Thank you.